# Using databse in VB6 how can I display data given in a form to another form?

Tags: vb6

In my VB6 project i have created company registeration form, login form and the main form(which deals with other activites for the project). Now registeration form and login form are working well and good but i am not able to display the company name in the main form which the user had enterd while registeration.

Tries:

1. i have linked the label(where i am supposed to display company name in the  main form) with the database which is used to record registeration details using properties of the label.

Basically what i want is whenever i login to the account using the login details i want to display my company's name in the main form (label1.caption) which i had enterd while registering.

Comment: Show us some code, specifically where `i have linked the label`, so we can provide some assistance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply refer to your login form in you main form's code. If your login form is called `frmLogin` for example and has a `lblCompany` label, you can access the label from the main form using:

```
frmLogin.lblCompany.Caption
```

There are better ways to do this though:

1. You can create a property on your login form and read it after you've displayed the form.

in **frmLogin**:

```
Public Property Get Company() As String
    Company = lblCompany.Caption
End Property
```

in **frmMain**:

```
Public Sub DisplayLogin()

    Dim frm As New frmLogin
    
    frm.Show vbModal
    
    MsgBox frm.Company

End Sub
```

2. Pass an object created in the main form to the login form that it updates during the login process.

Comment: Will this work if suppose there are 100 users having different company names if user x logins the name would be xyz and if b logins the name will be abc and so on. I mean the code should read the databse and display the company name in the lablel accordingly.

Comment: When the user logs in, their data is retrieved from the database and displayed in the login screen right? When you have that data, you can store it in a variable or display it in a label and make the Company property point to that. This will work with any amount of users.

Answer (score 0):

I added a textbox above Username.text which asks for registered company name which user had entered while registering and on my MainForm I added a label to display company name and on MainForm load event I entered `CompanyName.Caption = frmLogin.COMPNAME.Text` which displayed the company name while login

Note: I have linked COMPNAME.text with the database hence only registered name was allowed in order to move forward.